# PostgreSQL 'server closed the connection unexpectedly' when using the hostname (Azure VM)

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, azure-vm

I have a Postgres instance running on an Azure VM, which is inside an Azure Virtual Network, and the VM has a hostname.  Connecting with PostgreSQL using the IP address works, but when I try to connect using the hostname it gives this error:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Pinging to the hostname works. The connection goes through a DNS forwarder. The configurations of `/postgresql.conf` looks like this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'  
tcp_keepalives_idle = 120              
tcp_keepalives_interval = 30                                                  
tcp_keepalives_count = 9
```

and it currently accepts all connections `/pg_hba.conf`

```
   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

What is the cause of this issue, and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is the IP which you can successfully connect to the same one which ping reports for the hostname?

Comment: @jjanes That could be that case, there is another publicly registered/listed domain name which I use inside the VNet as DNS zone. I will give an update